# DoctrineCollection: difference between toArray() and getData()

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-collection

Basically, if I had a DoctrineCollection of DoctrineRecord objects, and wanted to convert it to an array, I could use:

`$collection->toArray()` or `$collection->getData()`

But I don't understand what's the difference between this two methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** See response [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41336773/1437934) for Doctrine 2. This response only covers Doctrine 1

```
->toArray()
```

> Most programmers would probably assume that calling toArray() on the
> collection would simply place all the objects into an array. While
> toArray() does do that, it also converts the objects themselves into
> associative arrays, which is likely not what you want.

`toArray()` is equivalent to this

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from('Post p')
   ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);


$resultSet = $q->execute(); // $resultSet is an array
```

[according to the documentation](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Doctrine_Collection.class.html#det_methods_toArray)

```
foreach ($resultSet as $post) {
    // $post is an array
    echo $post['title'];
}
```

so each element of the array is also an array associative.

Instead:

```
->getData()
```

> Not exactly the most intuitive name, getData() actually takes all the
> objects in the Doctrine Collection object and places them into an
> array – without altering the objects themselves.

so you will get objects!

```
foreach ($resultSet as $post) {
        // $post is not an array
        echo $post->Id;
    }
```

source: [here](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/10/how-to-turn-a-doctrine_collection-of-objects-into-a-php-array/)

Keep in mind this only works for Doctrine 1, for Doctrine 2 see answer below (or comments)

Comment: Note that Doctrine 2's `Collection` class is simply a wrapper around an array; `toArray` returns this array without any manipulation.

Answer (score 9):

Just an update for Doctrine 2:

> ->getData()

has become

> ->getValues()

Gonzalo was right for Doctrine 1, but hopefully this helps anyone who also found this thread looking for an answer but encountered problems using getData().

(Sorry Gonzalo, I don't have the reputation score yet to comment.)